# Linux realtime audio visualizer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I'm looking for a program that will visualize anything that goes through my audio-output (in this case it's Spotify) and display it on the screen. Does this exist?

I'm running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11):

[cava](https://github.com/karlstav/cava) is a fun one. It's a console application, so it's fairly lightweight. You can also run it in an ssh session from a different computer on the network.

Answer (score 10):

Try using [projectM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/projectM).

[image]

Either the packages is already in your sources or you can compile the source code from [sourceforge](http://projectm.sourceforge.net/).

There are packages for pulseaudio and JACK. ProjectM is able to directly use the audio output or your OS.

Comment: For 12.04 it's in the repos. Chances are good you want to install package `projectm-pulseaudio` (jack is also available). However I had to unmute an input monitor as described here http://askubuntu.com/a/532767/64513 in order to get some signal to the visuals. But otherwise: cool!

Answer (score 6):

[This archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130604035747/http://apps.linuxaudio.org/apps/categories/scopes_and_realtime_visualizers) from [linuxaudio.org](https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/start) has many different visualizers.

Comment: Had the same wish as Emil but I am looking for a "party mode" visualizer. All those on linuxaudio are too scientific.

Comment: This site doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: @evan.bovie RIP.

Comment: Here's a very similar page, without having to go through archive.org: http://linux-sound.org/scopes.html To @StephanSchielke's point, though, Cthugha is still the most interesting.

Answer (score 4):

found Synaesthesia to be both beautiful and easy to use, it also works well with pulseaudio through the command

```
padsp synaesthesia line
```

website:
http://logarithmic.net/pfh/synaesthesia

it is available in ubuntu repositories